# How can I encode parent-child constraints in a parse tree using the type system?

Tags: types, rust, parse-tree

I am writing a parser for org-mode. I want to leverage the type system to encode parent-child relationship constraints between the nodes of the parse tree. The problem can be demonstrated with the following examples:

```
enum NodeData {
    A {prop1, prop2},
    B {prop3},
    C,
    D {prop4}
//...and list goes on, each variant has its own set of props
}
```

The `NodeData` enum represents the set of possible syntax elements - kinds of data types in a tree.

The following `Node` struct represents the node tree itself in a very naive way

```
struct Node {
    parent: Node,
    data: NodeData,
    children: Vec<Node>,
}
```

This approach works until we decide to add some constraints to the way we build the tree, like:

- Node that holds `A` can only have `B` and `C` as children.
- Node that holds `B` can have `A` and `D`
- Node that holds `C` can not have children
- Node that holds `D` can have only `A`..

Generically speaking - a variant can have only it own unique subset of `enum NodeData` as children.

I have tried the following approaches:

- I can encode these constraints at runtime, but this creates additional performance overhead and still leaves a possibility to create an invalid tree (due to a bug in a logic for example)
- I tried using structs and traits instead of enum. (e.g. trait `CanHaveA` is applied to `B` and `D`). While that seemed feasible on the surface I noticed that I will lose access to the concrete type behind the trait (which I need since it is a concrete syntax tree) and unlike Scala I can't use `match` to destructure traits to a specific type.

The solution I hope to get should allow encoding these constraints at compile time and still provide access to a concrete type.

Comment: Did you consider combining structs and enums before jumping all the way to trait objects?

Comment: @trentcl not sure what exactly you mean. Can you give an example?

Comment: Meaning, you can make `A`, `B`, `C`, etc. all different structs, but still put them in an `enum`. The second solution, but without the trait part. Combine `struct A {prop1: B, prop2: C}` with `enum NodeData { A(A), B(B), ... }`

Comment: Still not quite sure how this solves the problem. Regarding first solution:
I do have  `enum NodeData { A(A), B(B) ...}` but this does not give me what I want. Node can have any variant of enum.

Your second solution also does not quite work. The problems are: `struct A` can have many instances `B` and `C` as children. And I need to maintain the order in which they were found in a document

Comment: Sorry, but you're not really giving me much to go on, here. `enum NodeData { A { prop1, prop2 } }` is not valid Rust syntax. `struct Node { parent: Node, ... }` is also problematic since it can never compile. Since the code in the question is sloppy, I threw out a sloppy guess. If you care to edit the question to be a little more focused, I'll give it another shot.

Comment: Tangentially, if you haven't read [Learning Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/) yet, you should *definitely* master that before you attempt a complex tree with parent links.

Comment: @trentcl, thanks, I will take a look!

Answer (score 1):

> and unlike Scala I can't use `match` to destructure traits to a specific type

Maybe it will be possible in the future (see [`get_type_id`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/any/trait.Any.html#tymethod.get_type_id)), but I don't see any problem with non-generic structures like

```rust
struct NodeA {
    props: NodeAProps,
    children: Vec<NodeAChildren>,
}
struct NodeAProps {}
enum NodeAChildren {
    B(NodeB),
    C(NodeC),
}

struct NodeB {
    props: NodeBProps,
    children: Vec<NodeBChildren>,
}
struct NodeC {}
struct NodeD {}
```

An abstract syntax tree can be safely stored this way, and if you need to do something generic with its nodes, then it's easy to implement all necessary traits for them. The Rust standard library internally uses a lot of macros for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I currently ended up doing. The problem is that I have way too many possible permutations of parents and children.  Generally speaking if I have 10 different node types it is 10*10 matrix of who can contain who. With this aside there are 5 different classifications (enums) which these nodes need to be part of so creating a ton of boilerplate code for converting between all those enums just gets out of hand...